# cannot access local variable 'color' where it is not associated with a value

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am working on a discord bot and one of the commands is /embed
The code is

```
temp = ' '.join(temp[1:])
                temp = temp.split(' | ')
                discr = temp[0]
                dic = {}
                for i in temp[1:]:
                    index = i.split('=')
                    index = [index[0]] + [''.join(index[1:])]
                    if index[0] not in ['color','title','type','url','timestamp']:
                        await message.channel.send("Error: IvalaidSyntax")
                    dic[index[0]] = index[1]
                keys=dic.keys()
                for i in keys:
                    color=dic[i] if i=='color' else 8359053
                    title=dic[i] if i=='title' else None
                    type=dic[i] if i=='type' else 'rich'
                    url=dic[i] if i=='url' else None
                    timestamp=dic[i] if i=='timestamp' else None
                
                embed = discord.Embed(discr, color=color, title=title, type=type, url=url, timestamp=timestamp)
```

and it gives the error message: `cannot access local variable 'color' where it is not associated with a value`

Comment: What is the value of the variable `color` if the `keys` iterable is empty?

Comment: is this indentation correct?

Comment: Did you declare color above?
Is your code within a class?
If so, I don't think you can change a local variable. You may have to declare another variable within the class if that's the case.

Comment: always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

Comment: If `keys` is empty, the for loop doesn't run at all, and so the `color` variable is never created.

Answer (score 1):

If there are no entries in `keys`, the variable `color` is never assigned a value. I suggest you get rid of the `for i in keys:` loop and instead get all the values without a loop.

```py
color = dic.get("color", 8359053)
title = dic.get("title", None)
type = dic.get("type", "rich")
url = dic.get("url", None)
timestamp = dic.get("timestamp", None)
```